# Laravel Get Method Not Supported Exception (While the form method is already POST)

Tags: laravel, character-encoding, cpanel, wysiwyg, arabic-support

I am working on a Laravel project in which I have a form to write styled text, inside the form I used WYSIWYG editor, and the method of the form is POST. Sometimes when I submit the form it gives me (*The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST*). **This usually occurs when I give some styling to my text**  e.g. adding background color or inserting Arabic Characters. but when I insert plain text English words It works as expected and every things ok.

I added the `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");` at the top of *index.php* file but the result was not changed

**Note:** the application works in my local xampp server, but when I upload online I get the problem.

Here is form.blade.php (view)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{action('MainController@Insert')}}"  accept-charset="utf-8">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  @method('post')
  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"/>
  <textarea name="details" id="myeditor"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('myeditor');
</script>
```

Here is my web.php (Routes)

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
Route::get('/form','MainController@LoadForm');
Route::post('/save','MainController@Insert');
```

And the is my controller

```
public function LoadForm(Request $req){
    return view('form');
}
public function Insert(Request $req){
    DB::table('notes')->insert(["title"=>$req->title,"details"=>$req->details]);
    return redirect()->back()->with(["message"=>"Note Saved Successfully!"]);           
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

to simplify it

```
<form method="POST" action="/save"  accept-charset="utf-8">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"/>
  <textarea name="details" id="myeditor"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```